# Computing the gradient of a function

Tags: derivatives

> **Function**: $f(x,y,z) = e^{-x} (x^2 + y^2 + z^2)$

I need to differentiate this equation for $f_x, f_y$ and $f_z$:
$\nabla f = \langle f_x, f_y, f_z \rangle$

**What I Got**:
\begin{align}
f_x &= −e^{−x}(x^2+y^2+z^2)+e^{−x}(x^2+y^2+z^2)2x \\
f_y &= 2e^{-x}y \\
f_z &= 2e^{-x}z \\
\implies \nabla f &= \langle -e^{-x} (x-2), \: 2e^{-x}y, \: 2e^{-x}z\rangle
\end{align}

Are these the correct differentiation?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: $f_y$ and $f_z$  are correct. for $f_x$ you must use the product rule since you have an $x$ term both inside and outside the bracket multiplying with each other

Comment: @thesmallprint I did the product rule and edited the original post. Does it look right?

Comment: let $u=e^{-x}$, then what is $\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}$? similarly, let $v=x^2+y^2+z^2$, then what is $\frac{\partial v}{\partial x}$? then, use the product rule. since you are partially differentiating, the product rule will involve partial derivatives too. just so you have a solution to compare your answer to, here's what you should get $$f_x=2xe^{-x}-e^{-x}(x^2+y^2+z^2).$$

Answer (score 2):

No. You have to use product rule. $f_x=-e^{-x}(x^{2}+y^{2}+z^{2})+2xe^{-x}$, etc.

Comment: @KavuRamaMurthy so I did the product rule and I got $-e^{-x} x^2 + e^{-x}2x$ would this be correct?

Comment: @user430574 No, when you differentiate $e^{-x}$ you have to keep  $(x^{2}+y^{2}+z^{2})$ as it is. You cannot drop $y^{2}+z^{2}$,

Comment: okay, so I added the things that I dropped, this is what I got. $fx = -e^{-x}(x2+y2+z2) + e^{-x}(x2+y2+z2)2x$

Comment: @user430574 In the second term you are differentiating $x^{2}+y^{2}+z^{2}$ partially  w.r.t. $x$ and the derivative is $2x$, not $2x(x^{2}+y^{2}+z^{2})$